# VLC avoid "interpolation" between pixel when resizing the window playing a low resolution video

Tags: resolution, vlc-media-player, scaling

I've got a video that has a original resolution of 80x60 pixel. Actually it's a color heatmap recording of a thermal camera. Now, when I'm playing the video I've got to resize the vlc window so that I can see more details, because the window is quite small. But when I do this, vlc does some kind of pixel interpolation (dont know how it's called), so in the end my image looks very blurry because of the artificially added pixels.

Is there a way to scale up the video in vlc, so that the pixels of the video just get bigger? So let's say when starting the video, 1 videopixel is mapped to 1 monitorpixel and when succesfully scaling it up, 1 videopixel is mapped to a uniform square of 10x10 monitorpixel.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I guess the key world is upscaling. This link may overlap with your needs: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=113743.

Answer (score 2):

Tried to figure out this myself, and this was the one I got working for Windows:

In VLC 2.2.4:

Tools -> Preferences -> Video -> Display: Output: Windows GDI video output (dropdown list)

Comment: Finally can play the "Move Your Feet" video as it meant to be. Thanks!

Comment: Anyone have an idea of any tricks to do this in Linux?

Comment: Nice to inform you need to restart VLC